# Connect markers on spinning globe with line in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am making the **spinning globe** [here](https://bl.ocks.org/atanumallick/8d18989cd538c72ae1ead1c3b18d7b54) in D3.js.

I would like to connect markers (cities) by their longitude and latitude using a line.

I can successfully create a line on the globe like this:

```
var link = [
    {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[100, 200], [50, 30]]}
]

// Add the path
svg.selectAll("myPath")
  .data(link)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d){ return path(d)})
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "orange")
    .style("stroke-width", 7)
```

But the line does not project correctly on the globe when I put in longitude and latitude values in the link data. The ends of the line do not touch the cities even though the longitude and latitude between the 2 points are specified.

Comment: try this: http://bl.ocks.org/tlfrd/df1f1f705c7940a6a7c0dca47041fec8

Comment: One of those isn't a valid lat long pair, can you share the data you have used, and what cities they are supposed to correspond to?